# Build proccess in VS team services incorrectly maps Win32 to x64

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, platform-specific, azure-pipelines-build-task

I've set up a build process in Visual Studio Team Services for a UWP solution using an agent on my box. My solution contains a mix of C++ and managed projects (2 projects are C++, other are C#). My problem is that `x86` build fails, while for `x64` and `ARM` platforms the build completes successfully.

From what I'm seeing from the build log, it is incorrectly treating `Win32` platform as `x64`, and putting the resulting `*.lib` file into `bin\Release\x64` folder instead of `bin\Release\Win32`, where the next project is supposed to pick it up from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\Lib.exe /OUT:"C:\Agent\_work\1\s\MyProj\MyProject1\bin\Release\x64\MyProject1.lib" /NOLOGO /LTCG C:\Agent\_work\1\s\MyProj\MyProject1\obj\Release\x64\test.obj
```

Any suggestions on how to fix that are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the failed logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was happening because I didn't have multi-configuration set up. To be able to build the solution for multiple platforms/configruations, this is a mandatory setting. When I got that set, the build started to succeed.